# How to move .js from View to Separate asset - Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a seemingly easy problem but it might not be. I am new to rails. As such I am still learning the in's and out's of the asset pipeline. I have an understanding of the assets/stylesheets and can get those to edit my view. However, I cannot get my assets/javascripts to work. The js does work if it is embedded in the view however.

I was hoping someone could take a peek at the source: https://github.com/Brownkyle219/clemson-sustainability

and you can see it functionally here:
http://clemson-sustainability.herokuapp.com

(I am aware that there is a routing issue when you click on the other tabs). Ignore the google charts stuff. My main focus is at the bottom of index.html.erb about the slider. All I want to do is move that script to a separate file in assets/javascripts. Any advice would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your JS in `$(document).ready(function({ yourCodeHere })`

Otherwise, the JS gets executed before the elements they target are actually loaded and will not work.

Comment: I have tried this, both in the view and a separate file and the slider will not show up. Is it actually supposed to say "document"?